# Is every induced metric a convex function?

Tags: metric-spaces, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Since it can be showed that the norm is a convex function, does that mean that the induced metric also is a convex function?

More specifically: If you have a fixed point $a \in \mathbb{R^2}$, will the function $d(a,x)$ be a convex function, if $d$ is a metric induced from a norm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is because $d(a,x)=\left\| x - a\right\|$, which is a convex function of an affine function of $x$, hence convex in $x$.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, when you say "convex in $x$", you mean convex in whatever vector space x is taken from?

Comment: I just mean the function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}, f(x) = d(a,x)$ is convex.

Comment: Got it, thanks!